# How can we display labels based on a locale in a CQ5 Component dialog?

Tags: aem

I want to display the field Label  using i18N values based on the page locale. How can we achieve this in CQ5?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through this site http://multilingualsiteadobecq.wordpress.com/